# Signing error when trying to open executable created with raco (macOS)

Tags: scheme, racket, raco

I've been breaking my head on this issue and have come to SO to ask for some help. I'm running Racket v7.7 on macOS 10.14. I've built an application with a GUI (https://github.com/layetri/markoviser), and when I compile it with `raco exe --gui`, all is fine. That is, until I try to execute the created .app. The program seems to start for a few seconds, but then dies. Looking at the Console, tccd gives me the following error:

```
Failed to copy signing info for 10203, responsible for file:///Users/layetri/Development/markoviser/Markoviser.app/Contents/MacOS/Markoviser: #-67062: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-67062 "(null)"
```

...after which the program quits. Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I can do about this?